# Two way pipe communication on Linux

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe

I need to solve this problem : Make two-way parent children communication, where children is filter (done in c). You need to send filename to parent, then parent send name via pipe to children, after that children apply filter and send back result to parent via pipe.
I make filter in C 
`

```
char * readline(FILE *fp, char *buffer){

int ch;
int i = 0;
size_t buff_len = 0;

buffer = malloc(buff_len + 1);
if (!buffer){ 
    return NULL;
}
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
{
    buff_len++;
    void *tmp = realloc(buffer, buff_len + 1);
    if (tmp == NULL){
        free(buffer);
        return NULL;
    }
    buffer = tmp;
    buffer[i] = (char) ch;
    i++;
}
buffer[i] = '\0';

if (ch == EOF && (i == 0 || ferror(fp)))
{
    free(buffer);
    return NULL;
}
return buffer;
}


void reverse_string(char *s){

int len = strlen(s), k, count = 0;
char tmp;

for(int i = 0, j = 0; j < len; j++){
if(!isalnum(s[j]) || (j == len - 1)){
    if(j < len - 1){
        k = j - 1;
    } 
    else {
        k = j;
    }
    if(count == 1){
        while(i < k){
            tmp = s[i];
            s[i] = s[k];
            s[k] = tmp;
            i++;
            k--;
            count--;
        }
    } 
    else {
        count++;
    }
    i = j + 1;
    }
}
}

void lineByline(FILE * file){
char *s;
int g;
while ((s = readline(file, 0)) != NULL){    
reverse_string(s);
puts(s);
free(s);
}
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{   
FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (file){
    lineByline(file);
} else { 
    perror("Can't open file");
    exit(-1);
    }
return 0;
}`
```

I try to make one sided pipeline and it works, but I have zero idea how to make two-sided pipeline...

Comment: The usual way to provide for bidirectional communication via pipes is to create two pipes, one for each direction.

Comment: You can use Unix domain sockets, which are, unlike pipes, bidirectional. See `socketpair()` etc.